# Background thread doesn't always work in Android onCreate() if in debug mode

Tags: android

I have some initial processing I need to perform in the `onCreate()` method of my game activity. I have written the following to try to perform that processing off the UI thread:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    parentGrid = (ArrowGridLayout) findViewById(R.id.arrowPlainGrid);

    //populates the game board without blocking UI thread.
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final LevelFunction someLevel = new LevelFunction(parentGrid.getContext(), numRows, numCols, parentGrid, generateCardList(numRows, numCols), true);
            PlainArrowTest.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Look at me populating the level on a background thread!");
                    someLevel.populateGridCards();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

This seems to work just fine every time I run the app (using Android Studio) in "normal" mode, but if I run it in debug mode, the `Activity` won't load because it says I'm trying to manipulate UI objects outside the UI thread (more or less).
I would like to be able to debug my app without having to comment this code out. Have any of you run into this? Is there a way I can alter my code to prevent this from happening in debug?

Here is my logcat output:

```
05-23 00:21:52.792    2127-2127/bwg.arrow I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-23 00:21:52.955    2127-2127/bwg.arrow W/ActivityThread﹕ Application bwg.arrow is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
05-23 00:21:52.964    2127-2127/bwg.arrow I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
05-23 00:21:52.975    2127-2134/bwg.arrow I/art﹕ Debugger is active
05-23 00:21:53.184    2127-2127/bwg.arrow I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
05-23 00:22:13.540    2127-2518/bwg.arrow I/GameLoop -﹕ Started run()...
05-23 00:22:13.541    2127-2518/bwg.arrow I/GameLoop -﹕ Nap time! Sleeping for 16 ms.
05-23 00:22:13.567    2127-2237/bwg.arrow W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-23 00:22:13.567    2127-2237/bwg.arrow W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5d582a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-23 00:22:13.670    2127-2518/bwg.arrow I/GameLoop -﹕ Nap time! Sleeping for 15 ms.
05-23 00:22:13.730    2127-2134/bwg.arrow W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 24.584ms
    --------- beginning of crash
05-23 00:22:13.734    2127-2517/bwg.arrow E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-120
    Process: bwg.arrow, PID: 2127
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6247)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:867)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17364)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17364)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17364)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17364)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:360)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17364)
            at android.widget.GridLayout.requestLayout(GridLayout.java:1092)
            at android.widget.GridLayout.setRowCount(GridLayout.java:392)
            at bwg.arrow.LevelFunction.<init>(LevelFunction.java:54)
            at bwg.arrow.PlainArrowTest$1.run(PlainArrowTest.java:57)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-23 00:22:13.841    2127-2139/bwg.arrow I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5497(318KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 36% free, 726KB/1135KB, paused 98.378ms total 194.327ms
05-23 00:22:13.890    2127-2518/bwg.arrow I/GameLoop -﹕ Nap time! Sleeping for 16 ms.
05-23 00:22:14.001    2127-2518/bwg.arrow I/GameLoop -﹕ Nap time! Sleeping for 16 ms.
05-23 00:22:14.065    2127-2518/bwg.arrow I/GameLoop -﹕ Nap time! Sleeping for 16 ms.
05-23 00:22:14.126    2127-2127/bwg.arrow I/PlainArrowTest﹕ Oh look at that! I paused the background thread. You're welcome.
05-23 00:22:15.711    2127-2127/bwg.arrow I/PlainArrowTest﹕ Oh look at that! I stopped the background thread. You're welcome.
05-23 00:22:15.711    2127-2127/bwg.arrow I/PlainArrowTest﹕ Oh look at that! I destroyed the background thread. You're welcome.
05-23 00:27:13.929    2127-2517/bwg.arrow I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2127 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is right, you are manipulating UI objects in the background thread and this is asking for trouble.

Look at the stacktrace you get in the logcat output:

```
        [...]
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17364)
        at android.widget.GridLayout.setRowCount(GridLayout.java:392)
        at bwg.arrow.LevelFunction.<init>(LevelFunction.java:54)
        at bwg.arrow.PlainArrowTest$1.run(PlainArrowTest.java:57)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This says your `LevelFunction` running on the background thread calls `GridLayout.setRowCount()` (and then it tries to perform layout).

You must not do this. You should run all the code that manipulates views on the UI thread.
The solution here is to remove your additional thread (as pointed out by Bojan Kseneman in the comments).

As for the difference between debug and release ("normal") builds: debug is meant for debugging and, among other things, it means that more sanity checks are being run in the program.

Your problem with the thread is present in all kinds of builds but the debug builds are able to detect it early and throw the exception to let you know where the problem is.